# "error": "unsupported_grant_type" uber rest api

Tags: rest, uber-api

I am using Uber Rest Api and trying to get access token:

Step 1:

Calling the get web API - https://login.uber.com/oauth/v1.2/authorize?client_id=gdSzxhaqFwjXly338goebrVCh_A7ND8b&response_type=code

Step 2:

URL: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token

Request Body:

```
{
  "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "client_id": "gdSzxhaqFwjXly33",
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "redirect_uri": "abc",
  "code": "EBvazkPeZXbszs4MufjxA0poKUZuur"
}
```

and getting the response : "error": "unsupported_grant_type"

Please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks
Suresh Patel

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide full code so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First you should double check if you set the correct redirect url in the dashboard - needs to be the same as one on authorization url. Second your request to 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize' seems to contain invalid version. Please follow the steps of the [authentication guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/guides/authentication).

Briefly, you need to:
    •   Send user to authorize url. It starts by redirecting the user to the authorize endpoint: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI .You can add scopes as well (check 'scope' parameter on authentication guide)
    •   Receive the redirect with an authorization code. After the user approves the scopes the user will be redirected to the redirect_uri with an auth code that you can post to the /v2/token endpoint to receive an access token.
    •   Make a POST call to: 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token'
    •   Store access and refresh token for future use

Answer (score -1):

Try making your scope public.
To do that, add:

```
"scope: "public"
```

in your `param`